# display the database values depending on the selected date ranges in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

i have one requirement table in my database in that i have one column name created date..so what i want to do is when user select the date from date picker  i want to display the requirements depending  on the date..from the requirements table..

i have no idea on how to do this

Can anyone help me how to do this..

Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is when you are saving the data in the requirement table save it with the date field. So when you are fetching the data according to the date. You can pass the date in where condition of your mysql query and that way you will fetch records according to the date selected by the user.

```
$this->db->select('tbl_employee_attendance.attendance_date, tbl_employee_attendance.status, tbl_employee_attendance.employee_name', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee_attendance');
    $this->db->where('tbl_employee_attendance.attendance_date', $date);
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
```

In the above code $date i'm getting from the user and passing it in my model query to fetch date.
Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dt1").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-M-dd",
            
        });
        
        $('#dt2').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-M-dd"
        });
    });
</script>
From Date :<input type="text" id="dt1">
To Date :<input type="text" id="dt2">

Comment: that is my date picker..how you get the ;$date'

Comment: Pass your date through the controller to the model. The date which you are getting in inputs can be passed in the controller.

Comment: You can use $this->input->post('inputVariableName'); to get the values of the form where you are selecting date.

Comment: my column name is created_date so can i pass like this in my model 'created_date'=>$this->input->post('created_date'),

Comment: First thing you gotta do is learn codeigniter framework basics! This platform is to solve the problems. I can't write the whole code for you. This is not the way!

Comment: $this->db->where('requirements.created_date', $created_date); i got error in this line when i echo query it shows like  this SELECT * FROM `requirements` WHERE `requirements`.`created_date` IS NULL

Comment: Do you have any records in that column?? If there check the date format. Maybe that is where you are going wrong.

Comment: If my answer have helped you please do not forget to upvote!! I'm glad that i could help!